# Where to find library?

Tags: search, jar

```
import common.money.MonetaryAmount;
import common.money.Percentage;
```

googled, the only result I found is:

"Actually no, its maven dependencies packaged under common-aux.1.0.1.RELEASE.jar" which I also couldn't really find.

has variation of:

```
import common.datetime.SimpleDate;
```

It is related to SpringSource projects, I can't really believe the jar does not exist.

Thank You,

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the common-aux.#.#.#.jar is a JAR file which is provided by SpringSource as a separate JAR file to be used within classroom examples.  You would need to pull it from the files provided as part of the class and then have your IDE reference the JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

[FindJar](http://findjar.com/index.x) can't find it, either.  I'd check the package name.

It can't be a Spring class, produced by SpringSource.  Their packages start with `org.springframework`.  Do you mean that it's a dependency?

Google found this, but no JARs:

http://git.springsource.org/spring-payment/spring-payment/blobs/6434aa3f9b9e5fce917d4ecf6ecc03387e1ba86a/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/payment/common/money/MonetaryAmount.java

I think this means that you'll need to access the Git repository, check out the code, and build the JARs yourself.  Here's the repository:

http://git.springsource.org/spring-payment

It should be easy to sort out if you have a Git client.